# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException / UnsatisfiedDependencyException when testing Spring Boot app with Java modules

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, java-module

How can I mitigate that the `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` and the related `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` occur when testing a multimode Spring Boot app that has been configured with Java 9 modules?

After adding `module-info.java` files to my multi module project, my Spring Boot application test started to fail:

*test failure*

```
contextLoads  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
   Error creating bean with name 'second': 
   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
   nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
   No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.first.First' available: 
   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
   No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.first.First' available: 
   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

*folder structure*

```sh
parent
  |
  + pom.xml
  |
  +-- first
  |     + pom.xml
  |     + src/main/java/module-info.java
  |     + src/main/java/com.example.first/First.java
  |
  +-- second
  |     + pom.xml
  |     + src/main/java/module-info.java
  |     + src/main/java/com.example.second/ApplicationConfig.java
  |     + src/main/java/com.example.second/Second.java
  |     + src/test/java/com.example.second/SecondTest.java
```

#### Parent Module

A Maven parent module containing just the parent pom file.

*pom.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>first</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>second</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <modules>
        <module>first</module>
        <module>second</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

#### First Module

A simple Java module that only contains a single Java class and that does have any Spring dependencies.

*pom.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>first</artifactId>
</project>
```

*First.java*

```java
package com.example.first;

public class First {
}
```

*first module-info.java*

```java
module com.example.first {
    exports com.example.first;

    opens com.example.first;
}
```

#### Second Module

The application module that depends on the first module in addition to the required Spring dependencies. It its responsible for configuring Spring beans, running the application, etc.

*pom.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>second</artifactId>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>first</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

*Second.java*

```java
package com.example.second;

import com.example.first.First;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Second {

    private final First first;

    public Second(First first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfig.class, args);
        System.out.println("started");
    }
}
```

*ApplicationConfig.java*

```java
package com.example.second;

import com.example.first.First;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    First first() {
        return new First();
    }
}
```

*SecondTest.java*

```java
package com.example.second;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class SecondTest {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```

#### Observations

- The test fail regardless if I use Maven, e.g. `mvn test` or if I attempt to debug them from within my IDE.
- It is possible to start the application invoking the `Second#main()`, both from within the IDE as well as from command line using `java -jar second/target/second-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` so dependency injection and auto wiring works in this case (the jar file has to be built without tests in this case since they are failing, e.g. `mvn package -DskipTests=true`) so the `First` bean is created and autowired correctly in this case.
- The test pass if both `module-info.java` files are deleted, so the error seem to be related to Java modules

Comment: @xerx593 I'm sorry, it should be `src/test/java` as you noted. I have updated the post accordingly.

Comment: phew... i am glad it was only a typo! :-) next issue: final field constructor of that bean (it is too early!) (cause/root of the error message)

Comment: ..and last: you can(*should*!) have `src/main/java/module-info.java`**+** `src/test/java/module-info.java` ;);)  (or does your "main requires junit" (e.g.)?)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow? Adding `@SpringApplication` implies (according to its JavaDoc) that "Indicates a configuration class that declares one or more @Bean methods and also triggers auto-configuration and component scanning. This is a convenience annotation that is equivalent to declaring @Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan."

Comment: And by "too early", why does dependency injection work when starting the app from the `main` method? And why does it work when executing the tests without the `module-info.java` files? It should be "equally early" in those cases?

Comment: yes, all true, good, but not contradicting with the fact that it is "too early"(..for the details, we can crawl the source code, but I assume/it sounds plausible to me: we should not "constuctor inject" (final field) on a "root configuration"...we have alternatives)

Comment: In Spring: @Configuration is also a "@Bean" ...and like any "defautl configuration" it has default scope.: singleton....one object is created (by spring) when it is accessed...and we get the same object whenever we access it again...)

Comment: I assume: removing `final` (and constructor), adding `@Autowired`, will already fix... alternatively: make `ApplkicationConfig` "a child" of "SpringBootApp" (`Second`) ((static) inner class), alternatively: declare it (@Bean) directly in `Second`

Comment: How can `Second` "@Import" `ApplicationConfigurtaion` before knowing `First` i.e. being created??

Comment: so we can tackle the "import" (inner config/bean e.g.), or the "before knowing vs. being created" (field injection/ one of the above)

Comment: in the end, I created a separate `Application` class with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70742794/303598). However, that still does not answer why the code worked in the first place when before the `module-info.java` were created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the feedback in the comments by @xerx593, I have implemented a workaround in which I have pulled out the `@SpringBootApplication` class to a separate `Application` class and updated the test accordingly:

```sh
  |
  +-- second
  |     + pom.xml
  |     + src/main/java/module-info.java
  |     + src/main/java/com.example.second/Application.java
  |     + src/main/java/com.example.second/ApplicationConfig.java
  |     + src/main/java/com.example.second/Second.java
  |     + src/test/java/com.example.second/ApplicationTest.java
```

*Application.java*

```java
package com.example.second;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

*ApplicationConfig.java*

```java
package com.example.second;

import com.example.first.First;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    First first() {
        return new First();
    }
}
```

*Second.java*

```java
package com.example.second;

import com.example.first.First;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Second {

    private final First first;

    public Second(First first) {
        this.first = first;
    }
}
```

*ApplicationTest.java*

```java
package com.example.second;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
class ApplicationTest {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }
}
```